# Correct fftw installation enabling Rcartogram

Tags: r, homebrew, package, fftw, c-libraries

I would like to instal [***FFTW***](http://www.fftw.org/download.html) to enable the [**`Rcartogram`**](https://github.com/omegahat/Rcartogram) package.

## Attempts

### `homebrew`

After installing [`fftw`](http://www.fftw.org/download.html) libraries via `homebrew`:

```
brew install fftw --with-fortran --with-mpi --with-openmp --enable-float
```

The attempt to install the [**`Rcartogram`**](https://github.com/omegahat/Rcartogram) fails with the following error:

```
>> devtools::install_github("omegahat/Rcartogram")
Downloading GitHub repo omegahat/Rcartogram@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/omegahat/Rcartogram/zipball/master
Installing Rcartogram
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ  \
  --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/private/var/folders/7x/kwc1y_l96t55_rwlv35mg8xh0000gn/T/Rtmp7nMfM9/devtoolsa9f2458e68c3/omegahat-Rcartogram-715cb93'  \
  --library='/Users/whereIkeepMyStuff' --install-tests

* installing *source* package ‘Rcartogram’ ...
(...)
Can compile with fftw3.h
checking for fftw_malloc in -lfftw3... no
configure: error: "cannot link to libfftw3"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rcartogram’
* removing (...)
Error: Command failed (1)
```

### `make install`

As a second approach I tried the guidelines available [here](http://okomestudio.net/biboroku/?p=719) and install [***FFTW***](http://www.fftw.org/download.html) using the following syntax:

```
wget http://www.fftw.org/fftw-3.3.6-pl1.tar.gz
tar -xvzf fftw-3.3.6-pl1.tar.gz
cd fftw-3.3.6-pl1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/fftw-3.6.6 --enable-threads \
   --enable-float --enable-shared \
    CC="gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64" CXX="g++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64" \
    CPP="gcc -E" CXXCPP="g++ -E" F77=gfortran
make
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/fftw-3.6.6 /usr/local/fftw
```

This fails as follows:

```
>> devtools::install_github("omegahat/Rcartogram")
(...)

* installing *source* package ‘Rcartogram’ ...
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
Package fftw3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `fftw3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'fftw3' found
Package fftw3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `fftw3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'fftw3' found
Looking for fftw3 files in /usr/local
Cannot find fftw.h
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rcartogram’
```

## Configuration

- **OS**

  ```
  sw_vers -productVersion
  10.12.2
  ```
- **R**

  ```
  R --version
  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
  Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
  Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
  ```

*How can install [**FFTW**](http://www.fftw.org/download.html) so I could use the `Rcartogram` package?*

---

## Cleaning

After failed attempts I would clean:

- **homebrew**

  ```
  brew uninstall fftw
  ```
- **shell**

  ```
  sudo make uninstall
  sudo rm -rv /usr/local/fftw*
  ```

Comment: The `cartogram` package is so much easier to install than `RCartogram`. Is that any good to you?

Comment: @Phil Thanks for showing the interest. I've the other package but I also want to use this one and solve the described problem.

Comment: Oh blimey, you are a masochist then! It's a long time ago, but I think you had manually add FFTW to your `$PATH` on Mac. Don't quote me on that though...